# Created a project using android studio 1.0 and it wont work on the new version of android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, version

Im having trouble with my android studio. I recently clean booted my laptop and some apps were deleted and android studio was one of them. My android studio was 1.0 and I didnt update it since cause it might raise some version problems and now I cant seem to find or download Android Studio 1.0 and my project wont run on the new version of Android Studio. I'm really worried cause this is my thesis project. Can somebody help me out?

Comment: https://android-studio.en.uptodown.com/windows/download/92519

Comment: i tried  that but it says that: The following SDK component was not installed: sys-img-x86-addon-google_apis-google-21

Comment: what exactly is the problem the Android Studio is showing?

Comment: that one. i tried to install version 1.0 but its saying that sdk was not installed

Answer (score 0):

Google stops support for the older versions from time to time, It will be better to use new Android Studio rather 1.0. Solve higher version error instead of finding 1.0. Download latest version of Android Studio from here https://developer.android.com/studio